# Creating a function to combine a nested array without recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array as an example;

```
let arr = [['red','blue','pink],['dog','cat','bird'],['loud', 'quiet']]
```

I need to write a generalized function that prints all combinations of one word from the first vector, one word from the second vector, etc. I looked up some codes on here but they are all recursion or working only with the specific array. How can I write this code without recursion?

```
let allComb = function(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    let result = [];
    let arrComb = allComb(arr.slice(1));
    for (let i = 0; i < arrComb.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[0][j] + ' ' + arrComb[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
} 

allComb(arr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version uses a single increment per cycle technique with no recursion.

```js
let arr = [
  ['red', 'blue', 'pink'],
  ['dog', 'cat', 'bird'],
  ['loud', 'quiet']
];

function allComb(arr) {
  var total = 1;
  var current = [];
  var result = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    total *= arr[j].length;
    current[j] = 0;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var inc = 1;
    result[i] = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      result[i] += arr[j][current[j]] + ' ';
      if ((current[j] += inc) == arr[j].length)
        current[j] = 0;
      else
        inc = 0;
    }
  }
  return (result);
}
console.log(allComb(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do as follows;

```js
var arr = [['red','blue','pink'],['dog','cat','bird'],['loud', 'quiet']],
    res = arr.reduce((p,c) => p.reduce((r,x) => r.concat(c.map(y => x + " " + y)),[]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This solution is good but how can i use it with other arrays without factoring the code?

Comment: Other arrays..? You  may apply this to indefinitely many arrays and it will resolve the combinations in the required manner. The construction of each combined item is defined in the `map`'s callback at `r.concat(c.map(y => x + " " + y))`. So in this particular case the string items are joined by `x + " " + y`. If you like to use some integer arrays then you may choose to sum or multiply them like `x+y`or `x*y`. I hope this was what you are asking.